# How to set dateformat to mdy in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, date-format

I am using SQL Server 2005. When I execute `SET DATEFORMAT mdy`, it just the date format for that specific session. When I disconnect from Management Studio and connect back it does not take that format.

But I want to set it permanently. How can I do it?

Comment: Your time would be *far* better spent adapting to using unambiguous date formats (and/or avoiding representing dates as strings).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Per msdn:

> This setting is used only in the interpretation of character strings as they are converted to date values. It does not affect the display of date values.
>
> The setting of SET DATEFORMAT is set at execute or run time and not at parse time.

The only way to change it permanently would be to alter the sys.syslanguages table, and you aren't allowed to alter system tables like that. Your best bet is to create a custom date parsing function that sets the dateformat and returns the appropriate string value, but you'd still need to call that function for every date. Would it help to set the default language to "British English" instead of "English"?

Comment: British English isn't likely to help, mdy is American English.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup language at the instance level, you have to use `sp_configure`. Remember that, it affects all the future logins only. But, if there are existing logins, you have to execute `ALTER LOGIN ... Default_Language` . [More on ALTER LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

In your case, it will be like given below. For more information: [Configure default language at server level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-default-language-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
USE Database_Name
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 0 ;  -- English_US
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

You can read the languageID from  sys.syslanguages table and set it up accordingly.[More info on syslanguages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslanguages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Note:** You need elevated privileges for this [More on Security to change default language at server level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-default-language-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Execute permissions on sp_configure with no parameters or with only
> the first parameter are granted to all users by default. To execute
> sp_configure with both parameters to change a configuration option or
> to run the RECONFIGURE statement, a user must be granted the ALTER
> SETTINGS server-level permission. The ALTER SETTINGS permission is
> implicitly held by the sysadmin and serveradmin fixed server roles.